# How to get the Windows path to Cygwin home directory?

Tags: cygwin

How can I programmatically determine the current Cygwin user's home directory in Windows format (e.g. C:\cygwin\home\user) so I can read from it outside of Cygwin Bash?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can use [`cygpath`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html):

```
cygpath -w ~
```

Example output:

```
C:\Users\dhaley
```